# Simple way to implement an efficient framebuffer in a modern language?

Tags: c#, java, graphics, d, framebuffer

I'm looking for a simple way to implement a framebuffer in C#, D or Java. Something (an API or library) that would allow me to work with a 2d array of colors and update individual pixels or areas. Also, something that doesn't incur large overhead on update. I know that this can be done with OpenGL, but the API seems far too complicated for what I'm doing.

Comment: What kind of operations? Reading/writing pixels can be done easily in array. Is this all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a plain old `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in .NET?
You could use `Bitmap.Lockbits()` to get access to the byte array behind the bitmap and update it. This is much more efficient than normal pixel operations on the bitmap.

MSDN has an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) that I've pasted from:

```
private void LockUnlockBitsExample(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a new bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\fakePhoto.jpg");

        // Lock the bitmap's bits.  
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
            bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

        // Set every third value to 255. A 24bpp bitmap will look red.  
        for (int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 3)
            rgbValues[counter] = 255;

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);

        // Unlock the bits.
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        // Draw the modified image.
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 150);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays will take lots of time while iterating through such large amount pixel data for a complete screen. It will be better to find something that doesn't needs or need very less amount of iteration. Something more like pointers in C.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a 2D array, In C# you can create a [multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) that gives you direct access to every member. To make this efficient, try to avoid frequent boxing and unboxing and don't allocate and deallocate large memory chunks frequently, and if you do it right there's no reason why this task would be much less efficient in C# or Java than in other languages.